# Django: use content_type of parent model for GenericTabularInline

Tags: django, django-admin, django-contenttypes, generic-foreign-key

In Django 1.8, I have a parent class and a child class, which are not `abstract`:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    ...

class Child(Parent):
    ...
```

and I have another model, which has a GenericForeignKey:

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    ...
    content_type = ...
    object_id = ...
    content_object = GenericForeignKey(...)
    ...
```

Now I want to build `ParentModelAdmin` and `ChildModelAdmin` such that both show the same list of tags as an inline (`TagsGenericTabularInline`).

How can I achieve that?

Comment: did you try creating a Tabular Inline and then set it in the inline list of the admin models? Check here for examples, straight from the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline

Comment: @KostasLivieratos Yes, but if I add a GenericTabularInline in ChildModelAdmin, tags are created using Child's content type and so I cannot see them in ParentModelAdmin admin page

Comment: Did you find a solution here? I have the same problem.

Comment: Ok, well I found where you can force it. It's not pretty and it's not easy to override. In your ModelAdmin subclass you have to override `_create_formsets` https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10.7/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1791 There's a loop in there where it sets `formset_params` to pass to the `FormSet(**formset_params)` the `instance` property in `formset_params` needs to be the thing that owns the Tags in your case. In my case, I have a `BasicProfile` that gets moved to `Leads` and `Owners` and my `BasicProfile` gets `Notes` and I need the Leads and Owners to see the same notes